# How to register mscomct2.ocx in Apple computer

Tags: macos, macros, ms-word, activex

I have a word document with a form, that form uses datetimepicker control, it is in the "mscomct2.ocx" file. I know how to register it in a windows computer. but I need to run that word document in a Apple computer. When I open the document it gives following error;

"Microsoft Forms" Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run activeX controls on Office for Mac as it is a Windows-only technology.

Comment: So how I create a from which accepts dates in Microsoft word in a MAC environment ?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: You can use VBA macros and collect user input via the InputBox - but you can't show a date picker - you would have to validate the string after it was entered to see if it was a date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use alternative date picker by  [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/addins/datepicker.htm) on excel for mac